# JSON to XML conversion for Web Service Request

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is there any library/function for JSON to XML conversion in Zend (1.9)?

If not then can you please suggest me any other library?

Thanks!

Comment: try this https://sites.google.com/site/mynotepad2/developer-notes/javascript/javascript-convert-json-object-to-xml-string

Answer (score 1):

if you can use the [XML Serializer](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer) from PEAR, you can convert the JSON to a object and then to XML:

```
function json_to_xml($json) {
    include_once("XML/Serializer.php");

    $options = array (
      'addDecl' => TRUE,
      'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
      'indent' => '  ',
      'rootName' => 'json',
      'mode' => 'simplexml'
    );

    $serializer = new XML_Serializer($options);
    $obj = json_decode($json);

    if ($serializer->serialize($obj)) {
        return $serializer->getSerializedData();
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```